# Registros al azar MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo php para mostrarme datos al azar de una base de datos

```
<?php
    include 'cn.php';

    $consulta = "SELECT EM.codigo_persona,EM.Nombre,EM.Puesto,EM.Departamento,ST.tb_stdname,TA.TC_NombreArea_ar
    FROM empleados AS EM
    INNER JOIN tb_estandares AS ST
    INNER JOIN tb_area AS TA
    ON ST.tb_IdArea = TA.TC_IdArea_ar AND
       EM.Departamento = TA.TC_NombreArea_ar
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $resultado = $c ->query($consulta);

    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $usuario[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
    }

    echo json_encode($usuario);
    $resultado->close();
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si consigo que el php haga lo que quiero mostrarme un empleado y un estandar de su area al azar pero ahora lo que quiero es que me muestre al mismo empleado al azar pero con 3 estandares de su area en ves de uno como lo hace hasta ahorita y sinceramente no se de que manera lograrlo hasta el momento lo intente con consultas separadas una que me muestre al empleado y otra que me muestre los 3 estandares al azar pero no consigo que de la consulta anterior tome el valor del area por lo cual me muestra los 3 estandares pero diferentes areas.

Me podrian auxiliar.

Asi es como tengo la opcion de usar 2 consultas por separado una que obtenga al empleado al azar y la otra que obtenga el estandar que debera mostrarme dependiendo el area del usuario que halla obtenido en la consulta anterior pero no se de que manera lograr que la `$consulta2` tome el valor del area que obtuvimos de la `$consulta1`

```
<?php
    include 'cn.php';

    $consulta1 = "SELECT EM.codigo_persona,EM.Nombre,EM.Puesto,EM.Departamento 
    FROM empleados AS EM ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $consulta2 = "SELECT EM.Departamento,ST.tb_stdname,TA.TC_NombreArea_ar 
    FROM empleados AS EM INNER JOIN tb_estandares AS ST 
    INNER JOIN tb_area AS TA 
    ON ST.tb_IdArea = TA.TC_IdArea_ar 
    AND EM.Departamento = TA.TC_NombreArea_ar 
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";

    $resultado = $c ->query($consulta);

    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $usuario[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
    }

    echo json_encode($usuario);
    $resultado->close();
?>
```

Se que deberia reemplazar `EM.Departamento` por una variable que almacene el valor obtenido por la `$consulta1` pero no se me ocurre como me podrian auxiliar haciendo pruebas con la consulta por separado si me muestra los 3 estandares.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y no haces 2 consultas ?? Una para obtener al usuario al azar, la otra para obtener los 3 de ese usuario ?

Comment: Te comento que ya lo hice y si me muestra los 3 estandares pero me los da de diferente area, los estandares se manejan por area o departamento no por usuario lo que hago es que dependiendo del area del usuario me muestra un estandar al azar por eso les comento que no se de que manera en la 2da consulta hacer que tome el area que me mostro en la primera.

Comment: Ok, entonces muestra esa 2da consulta que esta fallando.

Comment: Listo ya agregue el codigo como lo tenia con las 2 consultas por separado

Comment: ya ejecutaste a tus dos consultas? veo que estás ejecutando solo a uno `$c->query($consulta);`

Comment: Ok, primero. La primera consulta trae 1 empleado, luego, con los datos del empleado, es que haces la 2da consulta. Y si, debes correr ambas consultas al hilo.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia como haria esto ?

Comment: Un seg. ahi lo muestro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, mas abajo dejo un codigo ejemplo

**DEBES EDITARLO PARA QUE FUNCIONE EN TU CODIGO !!**

Pero lo importante es entender 2 cosas...

1. Usas la primera consulta para traer un empleado random
2. La segundaconsulta la haces con los datos de la primera, no es random ya. Buscas al empleado de la primera consulta

En el ejemplo abajo he editado las consultas para buscar todo (*) asi que edita a los datos que TU quieres traer.

```
<?php
    //Conexion
    include 'cn.php';

    //Acá buscamos al usuario random
    $consulta1 = "SELECT *
    FROM empleados AS EM ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    //Ejecutamos la primera consulta para obtener los datos
    $resultado = $c ->query($consulta);

    //Cargamos los datos del usuario random
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $usuario[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
    }

    //El dato importante a rescatar acá, es el ID del empleado
    //La búsqueda ya no es random, buscamos a ese empleado
    $idEmpleado = $usuario['id_empleado']; //acá asignas el id a una variable para usarla en la sgte consulta

    //Acá lo importante, debes consultar, por los datos del usuario random
    $consulta2 = "SELECT *
    FROM empleados AS EM 
    INNER JOIN tb_area AS TA ON EM.Departamento = TA.TC_NombreArea_ar 
    INNER JOIN tb_estandares AS ST ON ST.tb_IdArea = TA.TC_IdArea_ar
    WHERE EM.id_empleado = $idEmpleado //Acá buscamos por el empleado
    LIMIT 3"; //Limitamos la busqueda a 3.

    //Ejecutamos la 2da consulta
    $resultado2 = $c2->query($consulta2);

    //Guardamos los datos
    //Cargamos los datos del usuario random
    while($fila = $resultado2->fetch_array()){
        $usuario2[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
    }

    //retornamos el array necesitado
    echo json_encode($usuario2);
    $resultado->close();
?>
```

Comment: A muchas gracias deja agrego lo que yo necesito y ahi te digo

Comment: Estoy teniendo problemas con las variables me dice que estan indefinidas

Comment: Estoy viendo que hice mal

Comment: `Warning: Undefined array key "Departamento" in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertandroid\buscar_producto.php on line 19`

`Warning: Undefined variable $usuario2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertandroid\buscar_producto.php on line 38
null`

Comment: Pues me da un resultado de null

Comment: Puedes venir a este chat ??? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141548/registros-al-azar-mysql

Comment: `echo json_encode($usuario);
    $resultado->close();` al llamar a la consulta uno si me muestra los datos del empleado pero al llamar la consulta2 con `$usuario2` es cuando me dice `Warning: Undefined variable $usuario2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertandroid\buscar_producto.php on line 38`

Comment: Yo creo que el problema es por el array '$depar = $usuario['Departamento'];'

Comment: Listo ya me inclui